# How to exclude execution of certain specflow tests marked with @ignore keyword in Azure Pipeline

Tags: specflow, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have many `specflow`  feature files in my solution and there are multiple UI test cases.
At the page level, I have defined a tag eg `@Feature1` for the first file and `@feature2` for the second file. They are passed onto as the `parameter` in the `yaml` file
I pass the tag to my pipeline `yml`.  Now I am in a situation wherein I have few test cases marked as `@ignore` as well
So then the pipeline runs, these test cases are not exculded but eventually fail.
I want to skip the test cases marked with the `@ignore` attribute/tag.
Here is a snippet from my pipeline

```yaml
  parameters:
  - name: 'featuresToRun'
    type: object
    default:
    - Performance
    - AutoComplete
    - Benches
    - CATMI
    - Export
    - GemIntegration
    - Keyboard
    - MainMenu
    - NewVoyages
    - ReferenceData
    - Settings
    - SimilarVoyages
    - Validation
    - Views
    - VolumeConversion
    - Voyages
    - LaycanRanges

trigger: none

jobs:
- job: startVM
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

  steps:
  - checkout: none

  

- job: runTests
  timeoutInMinutes: 1800
  dependsOn: startVM
  condition: not(canceled())

  pool:
    name: 'UI Automation'

  steps:

  - task: ScreenResolutionUtility@1
    inputs:
      displaySettings: 'optimal'

  - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
    inputs:
      packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
      versionSelector: 'latestStable'

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
      feedsToUse: 'config'

  - task: MSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: 'UIAutomation.sln'
      msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
      clean: true

  - ${{each feature in parameters.featuresToRun}}:
    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: ${{feature}} Tests
      inputs:
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          UIAutomation.Specs\bin\Debug\UIAutomation.Specs.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        uiTests: true
        testRunTitle: '${{feature}}'
        testFiltercriteria: 'Category=${{feature}}'        
        rerunFailedTests: true
        rerunMaxAttempts: 2
        rerunFailedThreshold: 80
        codeCoverageEnabled: true
      continueOnError: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `testFiltercriteria` to exclude that category:

```
testFiltercriteria: 'Category=${{feature}}&Category!=ignore'
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

it appears the `testFiltercriteria` property translates to the `--filter` argument to `dotnet test` or the `--testcasefilter:<Expression>` argument to vstest.console.exe.

The `@ignore` tag in Gherkin gets translates to a `[TestCategory(...)]` attribute above the test methods (when using MS Test). Other unit test providers have a similar conversion.

More info:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/main/docs/filter.md
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options